# Selenium: PhantomJS: Website is rendered as mobile site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, viewport, headless-browser

I'm trying to run my selenium automation scripts which are in java using the PhantomJS headless browser. The script runs fine in IE11 in head full mode.

When I run the script using the PhantomJS the website is rendered as mobile site and the element becomes not visible and the script fails. Please suggest how can I overcome this situation.

I'm using the below code to instantiate the PhantomJS

```
if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("PhantomJS")) {                    
            WebDriverManager.phantomjs().setup();
            driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();            
}
```

Comment: if you are using phantom js then it's headless. You can't see the browser.

Answer (score 0):

When *PhantomJS* starts up the default **viewportSize** is **`400 px wide`** and **`300 px high`**.

As per the [comment](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10619#issuecomment-14993686) in the discussion [Render not honoring viewport size](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10619) @ariya mentions:

> **Viewport size** in PhantomJS follows the same meaning as viewport in WebKit. A web page here is more like a long sheet of paper where the content is capture. A browser however adds the concept of window viewport which is scrollable, hence making the behavior different.

---

### viewportSize

As per the documentation of [viewportSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) for *PhantomJS*:

```
viewportSize {object}

This property sets the size of the viewport for the layout process. It is useful to set the preferred initial size before loading the page, e.g. to choose between 'landscape' vs 'portrait'.

Because PhantomJS is headless (nothing is shown), viewportSize effectively simulates the size of the window like in a traditional browser.
```

Example:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 480,
  height: 800
};
```

### Solution

There are two possible solutions as follows:

- Configure the *WebDriver* instance with the required `window size`:

  ```
  driver.set_window_size(1024,68)
  ```
- Change the `viewportSize` as follows:

  ```
  var phantomJSDriverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(phantomJSDirectory);
  phantomJSDriverService.phantomjs.page.viewportSize = "{ width: 1024, height: 768 }";
  var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(phantomJSDriverService);
  ```